# AS3 Set Combobox background color?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following code which styles my comboBox drop down, but I can't seem to get a background color to work. I've used // comments to show which lines it doesn't like:

```
var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myTextFormat.font = "Arial";
myTextFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;
myTextFormat.size = 10;
myTextFormat.background = true; // Doesn't like this line
myTextFormat.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF; // Doesn't like this line

var m = 0;
function comboBoxChange(e:Event):void {
var scriptVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    trace("YOU CHANGED ME!!!"); 
    //scriptVars["InstructorName" + [m]] = myXML.Instructors.InstructorName[m];
    trace(e.target.selectedItem.label);


    //Change the comboBox color if Instructor selected
    // Go back to plain if no Instructor
    if (e.target.selectedIndex == 0){
        trace("EMPTY");
        e.target.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform;
    }
    else
    {
        // Shade of black indicates slot allocated to Instructor
        my_color.color = 0x002222;
        //e.target.transform.colorTransform = my_color;
        e.target.parent.alpha = 1;
        e.target.textField.setStyle ("textFormat",myTextFormat);
    }

}
```

Comment: This seemed to work:    e.target.textField.textField.background = true;
   e.target.textField.textField.backgroundColor = 0x000000;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to work: 
    e.target.textField.textField.background = true;    e.target.textField.textField.backgroundColor = 0x000000;

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you're looking for is the `contentBackgroundColor` style of `ComboBox`?

```
s|ComboBox {
   contentBackgroundColor: red;
}
```

or

```
combo.setStyle('contentBackgroundColor', 'red');
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. It doesn't produce any errors though. I used this: e.target.setStyle('contentBackgroundColor', 0x000000);